# No profile for team '***' matching 'match AppStore com.earth.dolphin' found

Tags: ios

when I am using fastlane to build my app write by flutter in Github Actions like this:

```
  - name: Deploy to TestFlight
      run: |
        cd ./ios && bundle exec fastlane beta
      env:
        TEAM_ID: ${{ secrets.TEAM_ID }}
        ITC_TEAM_ID: ${{ secrets.ITC_TEAM_ID }}
        FASTLANE_USER: ${{ secrets.FASTLANE_USER }}
        FASTLANE_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.FASTLANE_PASSWORD }}
        FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD }}
        FASTLANE_SESSION: ${{ secrets.FASTLANE_SESSION }}
        MATCH_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.MATCH_PASSWORD }}
        MATCH_KEYCHAIN_NAME: ${{ secrets.MATCH_KEYCHAIN_NAME }}
        MATCH_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.MATCH_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD }}
        DELIVER_ITMSTRANSPORTER_ADDITIONAL_UPLOAD_PARAMETERS: ${{ secrets.DELIVER_ITMSTRANSPORTER_ADDITIONAL_UPLOAD_PARAMETERS }}
```

shows this error:

```
[15:59:30]: ▸ ❌  error: No profile for team '***' matching 'match AppStore com.earth.dolphin' found: Xcode couldn't find any provisioning profiles matching '***/match AppStore com.earth.dolphin'. Install the profile (by dragging and dropping it onto Xcode's dock item) or select a different one in the Signing & Capabilities tab of the target editor. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
[15:59:30]: ▸ ** ARCHIVE FAILED **

❌  error: No profile for team '***' matching 'match AppStore com.earth.dolphin' found: Xcode couldn't find any provisioning profiles matching '***/match AppStore com.earth.dolphin'. Install the profile (by dragging and dropping it onto Xcode's dock item) or select a different one in the Signing & Capabilities tab of the target editor. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
```

this is the config in XCode:

[image]

this is the server side config:

[image]

Am I missing something? what should I do to make it work?

Comment: Hi were you able to fix this issue ?  We have 2 targets the actual app and a NotificationServiceExtension but the NotificationServiceExtension throws no profile for team found error.

Comment: I have fixed this problem, but I do not remember how to fix it in that time. Maybe retry should fix it, it is not a seriously problem, I am misconfig somewhere in Xcode. @ahmetakil sorry I could not help you, but it is not a complex problem, be patient.

Answer (score 1):

Previously I had had that problem. I just readded my XCode account and it worked as it had worked normally again.